# the app created in the terminal does not show up in Eclipse

Tags: linux, django, eclipse

I am using Linux Mint. I created a poll app in the Django project in terminal. I can see it was created (executing command "tree") but the problem it doesn't show up in `Eclipse (3.8)` in the `files`/`folders` list of the project.

What is the problem??! Many thanks for help in advance!!

**Edited:**

```
(workspace2015) kasia@kasia-SATELLITE-L750 ~/workspace2015/kk $ ls -R
.:
kk  manage.py  polls  sqlite.db

./kk:
__init__.py   __pycache__  settings.pyc  wsgi.py
__init__.pyc  settings.py  urls.py       wsgi.pyc

./kk/__pycache__:
__init__.cpython-34.pyc  urls.cpython-34.pyc
settings.cpython-34.pyc  wsgi.cpython-34.pyc

./polls:
admin.py  __init__.py  migrations  models.py  __pycache__  tests.py  views.py

./polls/migrations:
__init__.py

./polls/__pycache__:
__init__.cpython-34.pyc
```

Comment: list the directory and show us ..

Comment: no not like this ... please click this http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27771796/edit

Comment: The more you edit your question .. ! More you will get good answer ...

Comment: thnak you. im using this forum first time - that's why this chaos :) ive edited the post

Answer (score 0):

The Question should be `How` `To` `Convert` An `Existing` `Django` `Project` `To` `Eclipse` `Project` ?

There's a tutorial for that .. http://prateekvjoshi.com/2013/04/01/how-to-convert-an-existing-django-project-to-eclipse-project/